# Getting data from Serialize data

Tags: php, serialization

What i'm trying to do is get the data from the serialized data. I got it where it inputs the power name, but what i'm trying to do is make it where it shows if the user has the power.

Here is the serialized data

```
a:1:{s:6:"powers";a:1:{s:7:"profile";a:1:{s:3:"has";b:0;}}}
```

Trying to get `has` part of the data but it just gets the name of the power.

PHP Code

```
foreach ($c['powers'] as $a => $b) {
            echo $a;

}
```

the `$c['powers']` is the start of the serialize data as you can see here `s:6:"powers"`

Comment: I did `$c = unserialize($dbUser['addons']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see how it looks unserialized:

```
var_export(unserialize('a:1:{s:6:"powers";a:1:{s:7:"profile";a:1:{s:3:"has";b:0;}}}'));
```

outputs:

```
array (
  'powers' =>
  array (
    'profile' =>
    array (
      'has' => false,
    ),
  ),
)
```

So `'has' => false` is not an element of `c['powers']` but of `$c['powers']['profile']`

Comment: How would I be able to show the value of `'has' => false,` like on my webpage? Would I need to make it an element of powers?

Comment: For example, in your loop: `foreach ($b as $c => $d) echo $c;` (will echo "has")

Comment: I know that but i'm trying to get the value `false` and make it return if the user doesn't have the power it will not show under their power displays.

Comment: `if(! $b['has']) do_not_show_power_under_power_displays()` ?

Comment: That worked but I had to fix it because for some reason with `!` added to it made it work the opposite like if 0 was set it would show the power and when it was set to 1 it didn't show the power at all. Had to to remove the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
$coded = 'a:1:{s:6:"powers";a:1:{s:7:"profile";a:1:{s:3:"has";b:0;}}}';

$decoded = unserialize($coded);

 $has = $decoded['powers']['profile']['has'];

var_dump($has);
```